# Server Socket java se puede tener dos Socket server en la misma red ?

Tags: java

He tratado poner dos sockets server al mismo tiempo pero no me funciona(su pongo que es por que los dos apuntan 127.0.0.1 pero ya estableci la ip a cada uno) tengo que cerrar  uno para que fucione el otro, pero ocupo que los dos funcionen al mismo tiempo alguna solucion ?  gracias.

Comment: Cada SocketServer usa un puerto determinado y ese puerto solo puede ser usado por un SocketServer. Para usar dos puedes usar dos puertos distintos o bien como dices cerrar uno antes de usar el otro. Pero no entiendo por que quieres usar dos sockets server usando el mismo puerto.

Comment: Tienes razón no había pensado en eso, los dos tenian el mismo puerto , lo probare gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Si hará lo mismo el serverSocket, mejor crea hilos, para las comunicaciones, en vez de levantar un socket por puerto.